# Выезжающий блок на чистом CSS

Tags: html, css3, hover, transform, transition

Есть коллаж с фотографиями, при наведение курсора на фотографию, необходимо чтобы плавно выезжал блок с текстом `(:hover)`, но получается так, что при использование `transform: translateX(-50%)`, блок выезжает за пределы картинки и естественно, он работает как нужно, только, если навестись на левую половину картинки, так ещё и соседние перекрывает.

```css
.uvlech {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 340px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: transform 1.6s, background 1.6s, opacity 1.6s;
  background-color: rgb(144, 132, 224, 0);
}

.info:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(144, 132, 224, 0.8);
}

.info h3 {
  width: 80%;
}

.boocks {
  width: 480px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 380px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-0);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.walking {
  width: 580px;
  height: 380px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-1);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.gaming {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-2);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.code {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-3);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.science {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-4);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="uvlech">
  <div class="boocks">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Книги — корабли мысли, странствующие по волнам времени и бережно несущие свой драгоценный груз от поколения к поколению.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="walking">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Если бы природа не была прекрасной, она не стоила бы того, чтобы быть познанной, жизнь не стоила бы того, чтобы быть прожитой. </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gaming">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Мы не потому перестаем играть, что постарели, — мы стареем, потому что перестаем играть.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="code">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Для меня долгое время было загадкой, как что-то очень дорогое и технологичное может быть столь бесполезным. И вскоре я осознал, что компьютер — это глупая машина, обладающая способностями выполнять невероятно умные вещи, тогда как программисты —
        это умные люди, у которых талант делать невероятные глупости. Короче, они нашли друг друга.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="science">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Наука — самое важное, самое прекрасное и нужное в жизни человека, она всегда была и будет высшим проявлением любви, только одною ею человек победит природу и себя.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отредактировал верстку и все ровно не понял, что автор пытается реализовать

Comment: Когда наводишься на блок, другой блок плавно наезжает на него и становится видимым - изменяются opacity (с 0 на 1) и transform: transleateX(c -50% на 0%). Естественно, всё происходит через transition. Нужно чтобы блок адекватно работал, а не занимал лишнее пространство и работал только на половине предполагаемой зоны (:hover).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не на тот блок `hover` вешали. Надо на само фото. Еще добавить `oveflow: hidden` на него же.

```css
.uvlech {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 340px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.uvlech > div{
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.uvlech > div:hover .info{
   opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(144, 132, 224, 0.8);  
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;  
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: transform 1.6s, background 1.6s, opacity 1.6s;
  background-color: rgb(144, 132, 224, 0);
}

.info h3 {
  width: 80%;
}

.boocks {
  width: 480px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 380px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-0);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.walking {
  width: 580px;
  height: 380px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-1);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.gaming {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-2);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.code {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-3);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.science {
  width: 340px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO-4);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="uvlech">
  <div class="foto boocks">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Книги — корабли мысли, странствующие по волнам времени и бережно несущие свой драгоценный груз от поколения к поколению.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="walking">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Если бы природа не была прекрасной, она не стоила бы того, чтобы быть познанной, жизнь не стоила бы того, чтобы быть прожитой. </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gaming">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Мы не потому перестаем играть, что постарели, — мы стареем, потому что перестаем играть.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="code">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Для меня долгое время было загадкой, как что-то очень дорогое и технологичное может быть столь бесполезным. И вскоре я осознал, что компьютер — это глупая машина, обладающая способностями выполнять невероятно умные вещи, тогда как программисты —
        это умные люди, у которых талант делать невероятные глупости. Короче, они нашли друг друга.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="science">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Наука — самое важное, самое прекрасное и нужное в жизни человека, она всегда была и будет высшим проявлением любви, только одною ею человек победит природу и себя.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```